# ORDER BY rows on view for LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, limit, offset

I have a view, which is reading from different sources tables and returns ~40 mln rows. Now, I want to extract this data in batches, using LIMIT and OFFSET.

```
SELECT * FROM combined_view LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 0;
SELECT * FROM combined_view LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 1000000
```

etc.

However, to keep it consistent and avoid overlaps / missing rows, this SELECT should be sorted by some sort of unique id, so that every SELECT returns all rows in the same order (and then filtered by LIMIT and OFFSET).

I was thinking of creating a temporary table from this view and then reading from that table (since every table has row_id), but I am not sure, that's the best solution.

Please advise.

Comment: select * from final_trips order by trip_id limit 10 offset 10;

with create table use this command 

create table st as select * from final_trips order by trip_id limit 10 offset 10;

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You know about `row_id`, so why don't you use `ORDER BY row_id LIMIT ...`. Why do you need a temporary table?

Comment: @forpas there is not row_id for view. As I mentioned, the data is coming from different tables with some joins / unions etc.  Trying select * from combined_view order by row_id limit 1000000 will result into Result: no such column: row_id

Comment: @forpas using rowid while selecting from this view will return column with all values = Null, checked already too

Comment: I missed all the view part in your question! Can you modify the view so that it selects rowids of the tables involved? Something like `create view combined_view  as select t1.*, t1.rowid as rowid1, t2.*, t2.rowid  as rowid2 from t1,..t2 ,,, order by rowid1, rowid2 ....`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not perfectly clear to me what you’re trying... BUT, If you have a select, which generates a "temp" table or view, you can also use `row_number()` function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    [PARTITION BY expression1, expression2,...]
    ORDER BY expression1 [ASC | DESC], expression2,...
) as num_row
```

[SQLite ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/)

And then you can use it in your where clause:

```
...where num_row > 10000
order by num_row asc
```